# How to create a composite index programmatically in spring Mongo data in Spring or spring boot?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

How to create a MongoDB composite index with Spring Data programmatically in Java?

Using MongoTemplate I can create an index like that:

`mongoTemplate.indexOps("collectionName").ensureIndex(new Index().on("fieldName", Sort.Direction.DESC)`.

Is there a way to create a composite key?

I saw that there is the class CompoundIndexDefinition that, by its name seems to be doing that, but I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 9):

You can create compound indexes on any collection using Spring Data programmatically in Java as below:

```
// Compound indexes on the fields: fieldOne & fieldTwo
// db.groups.createIndex({fieldOne:1, fieldTwo:1})
IndexDefinition index =
    new CompoundIndexDefinition(new Document().append("fieldOne", 1).append("fieldTwo", 1));
mongoTemplate.indexOps(CollectionName.class).ensureIndex(index);
```

The above example will create same index as on mongo shell:

```
db.groups.createIndex({fieldOne:1, fieldTwo:1})
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. But can you let me know how to create a compound index consisting of one textindex and other index as a non text index. append method of bson document accepts only 1 or -1. It doesn't accept 'text' .Can u pls help

Answer (score 5):

With Spring Data, you can create index programmatically using MongoTemplate or MongoOperations

```
    mongoTemplate.indexOps(CollectionName.class)
            .ensureIndex(new Index().on("fieldOne", Sort.Direction.DESC)
                    .on("fieldTwo", Sort.Direction.ASC));
    mongoOperations.indexOps(CollectionName.class)
            .ensureIndex(new Index().on("fieldOne", Sort.Direction.DESC)
                    .on("fieldTwo", Sort.Direction.ASC));
```

Comment: This should be the top answer, as its the most ideomatic way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the more appropriate approach.

```
@CompoundIndexes({
@CompoundIndex(name = "customIndex", def = "{'fieldOne' : 1, 'fieldTwo': 1}")
})
public class Entity {}
```

In spring boot JPA Mongo repository.

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried with my project, but it doesn't create the index in database after I checked, are you sure it worked?

Comment: Yes, I am certain because I used the same in my project and it worked.

Comment: I think it depends from the Spring Data Mongodb version used in the project, from 3.0 automatic index creation is turned off by default.
You can enable it from configurations with `spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true`